# Can Failure to Access the URL in an XML Schema or Document Cause my Application to Fail?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1

I'm usng this: http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate

The schema is down? My software doesn't work anymore. Gives me a message: Can't access to CDO Message. I'm using Framework 1.1 with mail send authentication and failed.

Anyone have solution?

Comment: Please try to give more descriptive title to your question.

Comment: @pho3nix: Since the answer to the original question is "no, that has nothing to do with it", I suggest you edit your question to not mention the schema URL, but just to say: "Can't Access CDO.Message in .NET 1.1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference name, not a resolvable URI. It's just used as a string representing some value, and your software doesn't actually fetch anything from there.

URIs are used as names because they are convenient, but it's often confusing because it appears that there should be something at the other end.

There should be more inner exceptions detail that explains the cause of the problem; could you post those?

Try following the instructions [here](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.2.3.aspx) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be very clear: those things in an XML document that look like a URL, and that you see in:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
```

or

```
xmlns:cdo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
```

Those are not URLs. They do not mean that .NET is going to access a location on the Internet when you are using the document. In particular, it is impossible for one of these things (which are called XML Namespaces, by the way), to be the cause of your problem.

As [lavinio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49713/lavinio) said above, post the complete exception and maybe you'll get some help. You should put a try/catch block around the code having the problem, catch the exception in, for instance, "ex", then post the result of ex.ToString().